# How to respond to "options" request from a web server in c++

Tags: c++, http, request, server, webserver

I have managed to complete: `GET`, `POST`, `HEAD`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, `TRACE` request methods as a web-server, but still need to do `OPTIONS` request method.

What is the right way to do it?
I have seen some posts about "allow" but I didn't understand it.
Can I have a little more information?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: there's a specification you could read.

Comment: My preferred solution is to return HTTP 501 (not implemented).

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. could i have this specification? i read it on RFC 2616 & Wikipedia and i didn't understand it... if i return 501 its a Server Error?

Comment: i accually need to have it until Sunday for a project that i'm doing at school, and i don't really need to know the exact code so i will be glad to copy paste it :) thanks